# Why does C# allow to assign anonymous object to class fields which are of class types?

Tags: c#, .net

Example:

```
class Foo
{
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

class Bar
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

...
{
    var foo = new Foo
    {
        Bar = { Name = "abc" } // run-time error
    };
}
```

Why does C# allow that kind of assignment? IMO, it makes no sense but easier to cause bugs.

Comment: Because anonymous objects are not same as named objects. You can change the type to `object Bar` and see...

Comment: @Afzaal Ahmad Zeeshan: That sounds like a reason for the code to generate a compile-time error. Yet it does not. That's what the question is asking.

Comment: You need to say `Bar = new Bar { Name = "abc" }`, or in `Foo` say `public Bar Bar {get; set;} = new Bar();`

Comment: What you have is an object initializer, not an anonymous object.

Comment: Related: [Property initialization does not call set for List<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37873193/property-initialization-does-not-call-set-for-listt) (which describes collection initializers, but is the same in principle)

Comment: You code uses no anonymous objects anywhere.  You're just calling an object initializer when initializing an object.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet Thanks. I see it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually not an anonymous object, but rather the use of [object initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) syntax.

```
{
    var foo = new Foo
    {
        Bar = { Name = "abc" } // run-time error
    };
}
```

The above snippet is actually the same as saying the following:

```
{
    var foo = new Foo();
    foo.Bar = new Bar { Name = "abc" }; // Fine, obviouslly
    foo.Bar = { Name = "abc" }; // compile error
}
```

The object name becomes redundant as it is already known with the use of the object initializer syntax.

Answer (score 7):

This is made possible because it would not cause a run-time error if the object had already been instantiated.

```
class Foo
{
    public Bar Bar { get; set; } = new Bar();
}

{
    var foo = new Foo
    {
        Bar = { Name = "abc" } // no error
    };
}
```

Comment: You mean to say "instantiated". Evidently the new expression is the one trying to initialize the Bar instance. It just requires an instance to be there to begin with, regardless of whether it's been initialized by the author's definition.